# Proving a inequality of a point inside a triangle

Tags: geometry

Prove that for any $P$ inside $\triangle ABC$ we have $$AP+CP+BP>1/2(AB+BC+AC)$$

My attempt: Since $P$ is obviously the center point I constructed 3 segments that lead to the midopoints of $AB$ $BC$ and $AC$, $(R,S,T)$ respectively. My argument was $0.5AB+RP>AP$ since $AP>RP>0.5AB$ and the same argument holds for the rest of the midpoints. Then if I removed $RP,SP,TP$ then $AP> 1/2AB$ and so on... is this the correct way to go about this proof?

Comment: Use the triangle inequality which states that sum of two sides is greater than the third side.

Comment: You can deduce logically the triangle inequality just by drawing the triangle and observing it.... try it yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the Triangle Inequality, we have:

$AP+BP\gt AB$;

$AP+CP\gt AC$;

$BP+CP\gt BC$.

Add up, divide by $2$.

**Remark:** The point $P$ is not necessarily the centre point, it is any point inside the triangle. Parenthetically, there are many notions of centre point of a triangle, which agree for equilateral triangles, but not necessarily for other triangles.

'